# Dataprovider to EExcelView

Tags: yii, phpexcel, yii-extensions, yii-events

lets say i have a table named

```
cars{
'id','name','brand_id', 
}
```

and another table

```
brand{
'id','brand_name',
}
```

I have a situation that i want to generate an **Excel report** with the following attributes.
`'name','brand_name'` i.e. `SELECT cars.name, brand.brand_name FROM cars INNER JOIN on brand WHERE cars.brand_id = brand.id`

So i created a dataprovider like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT cars.name, brand.brand_name FROM cars INNER JOIN brand on cars.brand_id = brand.id";
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
$this->render('doc', array('dataprovider' => $result));
```

Now i want to generate Excel file with result as a `dataProvider` so i write the following code:

// lets say i am doing this in view page named doc.php

```
$factory = new CWidgetFactory(); 
Yii::import('ext.eexcelview.EExcelView',true);  
        $widget = $factory->createWidget($this,'EExcelView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataprovider->search(),
            'grid_mode'=>'export',
            'title'=>'Title',
            'creator'=>'TNC',
            'autoWidth'=>false,
            'filename'=>'Report.xlsx',
            'stream'=>false,
            'disablePaging'=>false,
            'exportType'=>'Excel2007',
            'columns'=>array(
                'name',
                'brand_name',),
            'showTableOnEmpty' => false,
        ));

        $widget->init();
        $widget->run();
```

**I have included all the extensions that i have to.**. This code is working when i fed the `dataProvider` field with a **single table entry** .
But the situation arises when i include **multiple tables**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines don't actually make a dataprovider:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
 $this->render('doc', array('dataprovider' => $result));
```

You'll want to do something like the following:

```
$dataprovider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
    'pagination'=>false,
);
$this->render('doc', array('dataprovider' => $dataprover);
```

More info here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider

Comment: Do you know why i am getting only 10 values? i.e dataprovider reflects only 10 datas.

Comment: The default for a dataprovider is to paginate every ten pages. My answer I'd updated with how to disable pagination

Comment: I have probably 320 rows and 60 columns.. the pagination is not working for those huge.. It works fine with limited datasheet..? Any solutions..?

Comment: Can you open a new question about that? Think you'd need to do your data in chunks and might be good to get other folks' thoughts

Comment: @TNC don't change answers given to you by yourself. If you think something should be changed explain in a comment and the author of the answer will change it.

Comment: Slight Difference should be made on pagination field.
`$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cars')->queryScalar();
$dataprovider = new CSqlDataProvider($dataprovider,array('pagination' => array('pageSize' =>$count),));`

Answer (score 0):

This works for 2 tables, dont know works for more than 2 or not.

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($dataprovider, array('id' => 'brand', 'sort' => array('attributes' => array('brand_name', ), ), 'pagination' => false));
$this -> render('doc', array('dataprovider' => $dataProvider,));
```